# How to get function body text in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function

```
function derp() { a(); b(); c(); }
```

`derp.toString()` will return `"function derp() { a(); b(); c(); }"`, but I only need the body of the function, so `"a(); b(); c();"`, because I can then evaluate the expression. Is it possible to do this in a cross-browser way?

Comment: `a(); b(); c();` is not a valid expression though...

Comment: @FelixKling: Why is it not valid?

Comment: @user1600680: `;` separates statements and hence cannot be part of an expression. Everything that throws a syntax error when put into the grouping operator `(...)` is not a valid expressions. But maybe the OP did not refer to this technical meaning with the term  *expression*.

Comment: Oh yeah, I guess to be correct there should be an "s" at the end of "expression" since it's 3 separate expression statements.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
var entire = derp.toString(); 
var body = entire.slice(entire.indexOf("{") + 1, entire.lastIndexOf("}"));

console.log(body); // "a(); b(); c();"
```

Please use the search, this is duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179861/javascript-get-function-body)

Comment: Use `.slice`. It's the same, but less confusing.

Comment: Do You mean `var body = entire.slice(entire.indexOf("{") + 1, entire.lastIndexOf("}"));` ?

Comment: Yes, I do. `substring` and `substr` generally confuse people. `slice` is a lot more memorable.

Comment: I will update the answer :) so if people will look for it - they receive better solution. Thanks

Comment: If you find a duplicate, then please flag the question as duplicate and if you reuse other answers then also cite them properly.

Comment: It wont work for the native functions, just for the user defined functions

Comment: Also note: this answer is from 2012, before we could use arrow functions. If you try this on an arrow function it also wont work. Just use `func.toString()` when logging arrow functions

Comment: It won't work for functions that have parameters with default values. Example: function(myObj = {}) { console.log('Contents') }

Answer (score 11):

Since you want the text between the first `{` and last `}`:

```
derp.toString().replace(/^[^{]*{\s*/,'').replace(/\s*}[^}]*$/,'');
```

Note that I broke the replacement down into to regexes instead of one regex covering the whole thing (`.replace(/^[^{]*{\s*([\d\D]*)\s*}[^}]*$/,'$1')`) because it's much less memory-intensive.

Comment: `toString()` instead of `toString` but this is the cleanest answer I've found, thank you !

Answer (score 4):

NOTE: The accepted answer depends on the interpreter not doing crazy things like throwing back comments between 'function' and '{'. IE8 will happily do this:

```
>>var x = function /* this is a counter-example { */ () {return "of the genre"};
>>x.toString();
"function /* this is a counter-example { */ () {return "of the genre"}"
```

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment

Answer (score 3):

A single-line, short regex example:

```
var body = f.toString().match(/^[^{]+\{(.*?)\}$/)[1];
```

If you want to, eventually, `eval` the script, and assuming the function takes no parameters, this should be a tiny bit faster:

```
var body = '(' + f.toString() + ')()';
```

Comment: Turning it into an IIFE statement for evaluation is the most robust solution if the function takes in no arguments. Works with ES6 arrow function syntax too.

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this:

```
var content = derp.toString();
var body = content.match(/{[\w\W]*}/);
body = body.slice(1, body.length - 1);

console.log(body); // a(); b(); c();
```