# How to get all the contents between two curly braces with or without using regex

Tags: javascript, java, regex

**I have the following code segment:**

```
function test(){
   try {
   ---------------some contents-------
       }
   catch(e){
           }
}
```

**Now, I want the codes between the 1st pair of curly braces. The output should be like:**

```
   try {
   ---------------some contents-------
       }
   catch(e){
           }
```

How can I do that with or without using Regex? I tried using the following regex:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{([^}]*)\\}");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s); // s contains each line of the above text
        while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
```

But, It only fetches contents if its there in a single line or no multiple lines of braces exist.

Comment: Yes. But I didn't get any suitable solution

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: is this supposed to be Java, or Javascript? and really: you googled and tried some regex but you could not find a sollution for this?

Comment: Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{([^}]*)\\}");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
  while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
  }
I tried using the above code segment.

Comment: In your regex you exclude the closing brace in your character class (`[^}]*`). Since you want to match everything between the first opening and the last closing brace just use `.*` instead. _But_, since your test text seems to be code, I assume you want to match arbitrary pairs of braces. In that case use a parser and not a regex, since regex doesn't fit code that well.

Comment: `System.out.println(s.substring(s.indexOf('{')+1, s.lastIndexOf('}')));`

Comment: `It only fetches contents if its there in a single line` - use the `MULTILINE` on the `Pattern` instance or the prefix `(?m)` on your regex to solve this.

Comment: Thank you :) I got the problem solved with all of your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You could've searched [better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227735/how-to-get-function-body-text-in-javascript)

Use `substr` and `indexOf` / `lastIndexOf`:

```js
function test(){
   try      {   /*---------------some contents-------*/    }
   catch(e) {}
}

var testStr = String(test);
testStr = testStr.substr(testStr.indexOf('{') + 1);
document.querySelector('#result').textContent =
   testStr.substr(0, testStr.lastIndexOf('}'));
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Try It:

```
String s = "function test(){"
        + "try {"
        + "---------------some contents-------"
        + "}"
        + "catch(e){"
        + "}"
        + "}";
int bracketStartIndex = s.indexOf("{");
System.out.println("START INDEX = " + bracketStartIndex);
int bracketEndIndex = s.lastIndexOf("}");
System.out.println("END INDEX = " + bracketEndIndex);
System.out.println("OUTPUT STRING : " + s.substring(bracketStartIndex, bracketEndIndex));
```