# Is it possible to get the text contents of a javascript IIFE from within itself?

Tags: javascript, iife

Say I have an IIFE:

```
let imagodei = {};

;(async function(){
   let C = "12:19";

   imagodei.myIife = aFunctionToGetIifeText()

})(imagodei);
```

I'd like to define `aFunctionToGetIifeText()` such that `imagodei.myIife` is a string of the above code (not including `let imagodei = {};`). Does anyone know if this is possible?

I've seen these questions, but they apply to the case with a named function:

[javascript get function body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179861/javascript-get-function-body)

[How to get function body text in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227735/how-to-get-function-body-text-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use arguments.callee, it is only available on "normal" functions (not arrow functions)

```js
(function() {
  var x = 1;
  console.log(arguments.callee+"");
})()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a deprecated [.caller()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) method -

```js
let imagodei = {};

function aFunctionToGetIifeText(){ 
  console.log(aFunctionToGetIifeText.caller.toString());
}

(async function(){
   let C = "12:19";

   imagodei.myIife = aFunctionToGetIifeText()

})(imagodei);
```

You can get more reference from [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/how-do-you-find-out-the-caller-function-in-javascript)