# JavaScript: How to get function definition given function object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print an object to the console to see the values using `console.log()`. I see that functions are printed this way.

```
variable1:
    title:
        "hello world!!!"
variable2:
callback: ƒ callback()
length: 0
name: "callback"
prototype:
constructor: ƒ callback()
[[Prototype]]: Object
arguments: (...)
caller: (...)
[[FunctionLocation]]: functions_mapper.ts:10
```

Is there any way to get the exact function definition instead of the location? My use case is not just to output and see but to download it in a file. How can I do this? Thanks!!!

PS: Doing variable2.callback.toString() gives the function definition, but the object has different types of variables in a nested fashion. And we aren't aware of them. When doing `copy(object)` from the console is giving `variable2: {}`. How to make it store the function definition? Do we have to go to each nested variable, check if it is a function, and call the toString() method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get function body text in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227735/how-to-get-function-body-text-in-javascript)

Comment: Not sure why you would want to "download" a function into a file? What is your whole use case?

Comment: @Bergi I want to download the object into a file.

Comment: @Harry it is not possible to download an object. At best, you can download a serialisation of the object. But again, what do you need the object for? What do you want to do with the file after it has been downloaded?

Answer (score 3):

`Function.prototype.toString` should get you what you want.

```
Function.prototype.toString.call(function xxx() { return 1; })
> 'function xxx() { return 1; }'
```

You can just call `.toString()` on the function -- in other words, `callback.toString()` in your example -- in 99.99% of cases also, but `Function.prototype.toString` is more guaranteed to work (conceivably the `.toString()` of your function could have been replaced with something other than the standard implementation).